# Why “What if I told you…” and not “What if I tell you…”?

Tags: verbs, tenses, syntactic-analysis, conditionals

Exactly in which category of grammar does this type of sentence fall?

> What if I told you …

Why don't we use *tell* instead of *told*, as it sounds this event has happened in past. Can anyone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is the form we use in English for counterfactuals. Historically it was the past *subjunctive*, but in Modern English that is distinct from the ordinary past in precisely one case: *I/he/she were* rather than *was*. This is why some people say

> If I were to tell you, ...

(Others have lost this and say *If I was to tell you ...*)

Teachers of English as a foreign language refer to this as the **second conditional** (a phrase I had never heard until I started reading this site).

> What if I tell you ...

is the so called **first conditional**, and refers to an unknown future, rather than a counterfactual. With a first-person subject, there's not too much difference in meaning, but *if I tell you* is saying it is quite possible that I will tell you, whereas *if I told you* is considering it as a hypothesis, probably less likely.

See [Second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional) in Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: (+1)Limitations of communication-:technical jargon-:someone who specialises in a field while explaining to other persons  who are not specialists in that field uses technical jargon .Therefore, they may not understand the meaning of many such words.

Comment: Actually, the whole of the answer is the first sentence, which I might paraphrase as "because that's how we do it". The rest is commentary.

Comment: I have taught English language, and we do refer to this as the 2nd conditional. It is used for imaginary future events and is formed with "would" and the past simple (to put it simply). eg "What would you do if you had a million dollars?" (the "would" is implied in the example: "what would you do if I told you..."). "What will you do if I tell you" is for a likely event, eg "What will you do if it rains tomorrow" when the weather report says it probably will rain. "What would you do if I told you" suggests you are about to actually tell them, but it is actually still an imaginary possibility.